# How can I use the tab control's buttons without multiple pages?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm doing a class project for VB 2010 and the project was originally designed to use buttons. However, I found that using the tab control looks much better and makes more sense. I asked my instructor if this was acceptable and she really liked how it looked but said I needed to use code to change the properties for the controls on the page to meet the requirements for this assignment.

I could just go back to using buttons but now I am just curious to know if it can be done? So is there a way to use a single fixed page for multiple tabs? (I can resize it so that only the tab buttons show but I feel this is too hackish)

Comment: `I needed to use code to change the properties for the controls on the page to meet the requirements` what are the requirements? Please address a specific problem.

Comment: which tabs you are using? is this some ajax or 3rd party or just <li>?

Comment: Requirements are just to use code to change properties on the controls. So I want to use the event of clicking a tab without actually using the pages.

@Sohail Hameed, I have no idea what you are talking about... This is not a webpage. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: this assignment is window base application or ASP.net web based?

Comment: then u need to have a look in tab control for windows and then create user controls for each tab and link them in tabs.. 

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/TabControlTutorial11302005235835PM/TabControlTutorial.aspx

have a look in this ..

Answer (score 0):

It's a questionable UI since a TabControl is typically used to change the view of the contents of an area, and you are wanting the TabControl to act as an "action" on an object.  From the sounds of the project, RadioButtons sound like a more appropriate tool to use.

One way to sort of make that work is to keep the TabControl and the control you are modifying separate from each other, and just show a description of the action for each tab, like so:

[image]

```
Private Sub TabControl1_Selecting(sender As Object, _
                                  e As TabControlCancelEventArgs) _
                                  Handles TabControl1.Selecting
  Select Case e.TabPage.Name
    Case TabPage1.Name
      Panel1.BackColor = Color.Blue
    Case TabPage2.Name
      Panel1.BackColor = Color.Red
  End Select
End Sub
```